# authenticate in multiple domains using curl (php / symfony 1.4)

Tags: php, curl, symfony1, single-sign-on, multiple-domains

I am working on a SSO solution for my app.
I have a main domain accounts.mydomain.com where the user makes login. After logged in successfully, I need to authenticate the user in all my other domains.

Each time a user is logged in I create an authentication token and then i make a call to a connect method for each domain, which reads the token, gets the user from the database and then log in that user in that domain.

Everything is working fine but the user I cant persist the user session in the other domains.

**This is my code: (using symfony 1.4):**

```
My main login action:
<?php
     // get a auth token for the user
       (...)

      // cycle through all my domains and make a curl request to the connect action of each one
     // passing the auth token
      foreach(sfConfig::get('app_connect_urls') as $url){
                $url.= '?auth_token='.$authToken;

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

                $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);

                $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
                $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
```

**My connect action for other domains called by curl**

```
$authToken = $request->getParameter('auth_token');
// $user =  get user from token (...)


   $this->getUser()->signIn($user);
   echo $this->getUser()->isAuthenticated() // returns true;
    return sfView::NONE;
```

If I go to that domain the user is not authenticated. If I call the action directly the session gets persisted.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The cookies are not being set in the url called by curl.

Answer (score 0):

For SSO/authentication in applications of different domains I recommend to use [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

You are using php so [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) will be a nice software to build the IdP (identity provider) part.

To implement the SP (Service Provider) for symfony check this project: [sfSAMLPlugin](https://github.com/chtitux/sfSAMLPlugin)